# How to evenly distribute the selected animation keys in the «Graph Editor» along the X axis and separately along the Y axis?

Tags: graph-editor

How to evenly distribute the selected animation keys in the Graph Editor along the X axis and separately along the Y axis?
[image]
Advantage / application uniform distribution of animation keys:

1. Quickly evenly distribute animation keys of harmonic oscillation vertices by timing.
2. Quickly make a smooth transition through an even distribution of adjacent animation keys between two adjacent gait or run cycles.

Answer (score 0):

### Python script

[image]

```py
import bpy
from bpy import data as D

cube = D.objects['Cube']
curves = cube.animation_data.action.fcurves
# find the curve of interest, here rotation euler Z
curve = next(c for c in curves if c.data_path == 'rotation_euler' and c.array_index == 2)
points = curve.keyframe_points
delta_sum = points[-1].co - points[0].co
delta = delta_sum / (len(points)-1)
for i, keyframe in enumerate(points):
    keyframe.interpolation = 'LINEAR'
    keyframe.co = points[0].co + delta*i
```

Comment: Great! Thank you!